# DotPlot no R incluir linha vertical e pontos de cores diferentes

Tags: r, lattice

Eu precisava incluir no código abaixo uma linha vertical, por exemplo, na posição x = 5 e que todos os pontos com x menores que 5 tenham outra cor, por exemplo azul.

Os valores de uma variável podem ser lidos no eixo x, e o eixo y mostra a ordem das observações na variável (de baixo para cima). Pontos isolados nas extremidades sugerem outliers.

Obrigado

```
library(dplyr)
library(lattice)
n = 1000
df <- tibble(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10)
  )

MyVar <- c("xx1","xx2","xx3")

MydotplotBR <- function(DataSelected){

  P <- dotplot(as.matrix(as.matrix(DataSelected)),
               groups=FALSE,
               strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white',
                                    par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.2)),
               scales = list(x = list(relation = "same",tck = 1,
                                      draw = TRUE, at=seq(0,10,1)),x=list(at=seq),
                             y = list(relation = "free", draw = FALSE),
                             auto.key = list(x =1)), 
               col=10, 
               axes = FALSE,
               cex  = 0.4, pch = 5,   
               xlim=c(0,10),  
               xlab = list(label = "Variable Value", cex = 1.5),
               ylab = list(label = "Order of data in the file", cex = 1.5))

  print(P)

}
(tempoi <- Sys.time())
Vertemp <- MydotplotBR(df[,MyVar])
(tempof <- Sys.time()-tempoi)
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro carregar os pacotes usados e criar os dados de forma reprodutível, com `set.seed`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lattice)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 1000
df <- tibble(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10)
)

MyVar <- c("xx1","xx2","xx3")
```

Uma solução pode ser com um `panel` onde as cores sejam escolhidas e as linhas verticais sejam desenhadas por painel.

```
MydotplotBR <- function(DataSelected){
  P <- dotplot(as.matrix(DataSelected),
               groups = FALSE,
               strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white',
                                    par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.2)),
               scales = list(x = list(relation = "same",tck = 1,
                                      draw = TRUE, at=seq(0,10,1)),x=list(at=seq),
                             y = list(relation = "free", draw = FALSE),
                             auto.key = list(x = 1)), 
               panel = function(x,y,...) { 
                 panel.xyplot(x, y, col = ifelse(x < 5, "blue", "red"))
                 panel.abline(v = 5, col.line = "red") 
               },
               axes = FALSE,
               cex  = 0.4, pch = 5,   
               xlim = c(0, 10),  
               xlab = list(label = "Variable Value", cex = 1.5),
               ylab = list(label = "Order of data in the file", cex = 1.5))

  print(P)
}

Vertemp <- MydotplotBR(df[,MyVar])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]